# Protected Routes using react-context and react-router-dom

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication, react-router, react-context

I have created `AuthContext` using React Context API. Where I am storing `userData` (initially from localStorage if I have data there and if not found in localStorage then after login).

```
export const AuthProvider = ({ children }) => {
  // const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [userData, setUserData] = useState();
  useEffect(() => {
    const data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('whatsappCloneData'))
    if (data) {
      setUserData(data);
    } else {
      setUserData();
    }
    // setLoading(false);
  }, [])

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={{ userData, setUserData }}>
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

In my `app.js` I'm checking if there is user details or not and based on that I am allowing user to visit protected routes.

```
const RequireAuth = () => {
  const { userData } = useContext(AuthContext);
  
  if (!userData) {
    return <Navigate to="/login" />
  }
  return <Outlet />;
}

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Container
        sx={{ backgroundColor: "white" }}
        maxWidth="xs" disableGutters={true} >
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
          <Route path="/register" element={<Register />} />
          <Route element={<RequireAuth />}>
            <Route path="/profileInfo" element={<ProfileInfo />} />
            <Route path='/' element={
              <Home />
            }>
              <Route path='conversations' element={<Conversations />} />
              <Route path='status' element={<Status />} />
              <Route path="calls" element={<Calls />} />
            </Route>
            <Route path='/chat' element={<Chats />} />
            <Route path="/cam" element={<WebCam />} />
          </Route>
        </Routes>

        <ToastContainer
          position="bottom-right"
          autoClose={5000}
          hideProgressBar={false}
          newestOnTop={false}
          closeOnClick
          rtl={false}
          pauseOnFocusLoss
          draggable
          pauseOnHover
          theme="colored"
        />
      </Container>
    </Router >
}
```

In login page when user login then I am storing the user details in localStorage and in `userData` in `authContext`.

Everything works fine if I use button or links to navigate from public routes to protected route or protected routes to protected route if user is once logged in.

But once I refresh the page it went back to login page.

Reason behind this is that as I refresh the page `authContext` losses the `userData` so initially `userData` is undefined but just after few miliseconds when `useEffect` inside `AuthContext` complete it recover the `userData` from localStorage and sets back to `userData`.
But as initially `userData` was undefined `RequiredAuth` in `app.js` navigate to login page.

How to solve this?

Comment: Conditionally render anything ***other than*** the `Outlet` or `Navigate`, like a loading spinner, while `userData` is undefined. You can also directly initialize the `userData` state from localStorage with a lazy initialization function.